# Inheriting upwards

Tags: html, css

I have a dom element like `div`, `span` (with `display:inline-block`), whose width is specified, and is the only (non-trivial) child of another dom element like `th`, `td`, `div`. Is there a way to inherit the width value to the parent?

Comment: That's like asking if I can inherit my kid's genes.

Comment: @DaveNewton It is not as rediculus as you may think. In TeX, inheritance is upwards, from the child to parent; The width of a parent is the sum of the widths of its children. It is just html that inheritance goes downward.

Comment: It was (partially) tongue-in-cheek--DOM elements size themselves to their children unless explicitly set. I don't consider that inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do not set the width of the parent. The browser will sort it out once the widths of the children are worked out, and therefore the `div` for the parent can be calculated by the browser.